# magento cron job and error_log file too large

Tags: php, magento, cron

I installed Magento community edition recently and didn't do any intensive work on it with the exception of some design work and installation of a few extensions. I took a look at the error_log file today and it seems to be 6gb and almost maxing out my space for hosting. I thought this was unusual as the rest of the installation is less than 2gb so I opened the error log file (a portion of it, mind you, since its too large) and this comes up:

> [12-Mar-2014 20:31:33 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: SCRIPT_NAME
>   in /home/zongulsz/public_html/cron.php on line 39
>
> [12-Mar-2014 20:31:33 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index:
>   SCRIPT_FILENAME in /home/zongulsz/public_html/cron.php on line 40
>
> [08-Apr-2014 10:13:22 America/Chicago] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup:
>   Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/opt/alt/php53/usr/lib64/php/modules/memcached.so' -
>   libmemcached.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
>   directory in Unknown on line 0

Its the same entry over and over and over.

This is the cron job command I see in my cpanel:

> Minute    Hour    Day Month   Weekday Command Actions
>   13,29,31,49 *   *   *   *   php> /home/zongulsz/public_html/cron.php > /dev/null

And this is the cron.php file:

```
1   <?php
2   /**
3    * Magento
4    *
5    * NOTICE OF LICENSE
6    *
7    * This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
8    * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
9    * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
10   * http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
11   * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
12   * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
13   * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
14   *
15   * DISCLAIMER
16   *
17   * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
18   * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
19   * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
20   *
21   * @category   Mage
22   * @package    Mage
23   * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2008 Irubin Consulting Inc. DBA Varien (http://www.varien.com)
24   * @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
25   */
26
27  // Change current directory to the directory of current script
28  chdir(dirname(__FILE__));
29
30  require 'app/Mage.php';
31
32  if (!Mage::isInstalled()) {
33      echo "Application is not installed yet, please complete install wizard first.";
34      exit;
35  }
36
37  // Only for urls
38  // Don't remove this
39  $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] = str_replace(basename(__FILE__), 'index.php', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
40  $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] = str_replace(basename(__FILE__), 'index.php', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
41
42  Mage::app('admin')->setUseSessionInUrl(false);
43
44  umask(0);
45
46  $disabledFuncs = explode(',', ini_get('disable_functions'));
47  $isShellDisabled = is_array($disabledFuncs) ? in_array('shell_exec', $disabledFuncs) : true;
48  $isShellDisabled = (stripos(PHP_OS, 'win') === false) ? $isShellDisabled : true;
49
50  try {
51      if (stripos(PHP_OS, 'win') === false) {
52          $options = getopt('m::');
53          if (isset($options['m'])) {
54              if ($options['m'] == 'always') {
55                  $cronMode = 'always';
56              } elseif ($options['m'] == 'default') {
57                  $cronMode = 'default';
58              } else {
59                  Mage::throwException('Unrecognized cron mode was defined');
60              }
61          } else if (!$isShellDisabled) {
62              $fileName = basename(__FILE__);
63              $baseDir = dirname(__FILE__);
64              shell_exec("/bin/sh $baseDir/cron.sh $fileName -mdefault 1 > /dev/null 2>&1 &");
65              shell_exec("/bin/sh $baseDir/cron.sh $fileName -malways 1 > /dev/null 2>&1 &");
66              exit;
67          }
68      }
69
70      Mage::getConfig()->init()->loadEventObservers('crontab');
71      Mage::app()->addEventArea('crontab');
72      if ($isShellDisabled) {
73          Mage::dispatchEvent('always');
74          Mage::dispatchEvent('default');
75      } else {
76          Mage::dispatchEvent($cronMode);
77      }
78  } catch (Exception $e) {
79      Mage::printException($e);
80      exit(1);
81  }
82
```

Comment: Send a ticket to your hosting with the error log. $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] and $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] not set is their problem as is the absence of memcached on your server. To run Magento successfully you usually need an adequate hosting provider.

Comment: My hosting provider seems to be perplexed by it and I'm not sure if it's something that I'm responsible for or their system is faulty for not allowing Magento to run properly. I will get in touch with them again. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `ini_set('display_errors',0);` and `error_reporting(0);` at the beginning of your `cron.php` file.

Comment: This turns off the error reporting to kill those undefined index errors that you're receiving.  This is due to having undefined variables along with E_NOTICE turned on in php.  Alternatively, you could just add `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);` which leaves all error reporting on except for E_NOTICE.

Comment: Thank you Sean. I'm just worried if turning off error reporting is the right thing to do and not actually fix what the error_log is reporting. What do you suggest?

Comment: Turning off `E_NOTICE` isn't really going to affect much for this file.  If these two notices are the only ones showing up then adding `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);` will fix the issue and only affect this file.  You will still see all other errors.

Comment: I guess what I should ask is, what are these two errors and what do they affect? Are they crucial functions the system requires or just some error that has no impact on the function of the Magento system?

Comment: It's just a warning letting you know that you have undefined variables.  Other than filling up your logs, it has no other bad effect on your system.

Answer (score 0):

At server level there should be a setting that should be set to disallow Notice related logs.

In short you either do it at server level or via some PHP code.